# Anyway to build a local webserver without config your router?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2008, router, port-forwarding, localhost

I always config router / port forwarding, when I try to build a local web server IIS7 / Apache.

But this time, I don't have access to control router, we have any software, any ways can help to build a local web server without port forwarding / config router ?

( sorry, if just a stupid question, but I want to know :D )

Comment: If the router happens to have UPnP enabled you can configure the port forwarding without admin access! http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/PortForward.aspx there are also various tools and a windows component to configure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your computer has a publicly routeable IP, and there is no firewall enabled on the router, or between the web server and the Internet, then you don't need to do anything.